# Create Fragment and set view elements

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, android-view

I am creating a new Fragment and want to set some view element attributes. This is what I try:

```
new DefaultSlide()
                .setImage(R.drawable.logo)
                .setTitle("blabla")
                .setText("fubar"));
```

Here is my DefualtSlide:

```
public class DefaultSlide extends SlideFragment {

    @BindView(R.id.defaultImage)
    ImageView defImage;
    @BindView(R.id.defaultTitle)
    TextView title;
    @BindView(R.id.defaultText)
    TextView text;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_default_slide, container, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        return view;
    }

    public DefaultSlide setImage(int image) {
        defImage.setImageResource(image);
        return this;
    }

    public DefaultSlide setTitle(String title) {
        this.title.setText(title);
        return this;
    }

    public DefaultSlide setText(String text) {
        this.text.setText(text);
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public int backgroundColor() {
        return R.color.backgroundColor;
    }

    @Override
    public int buttonsColor() {
        return R.color.colorPrimary;
    }
}
```

The problem is, that I get a nullpointer exception. My guess is that the view elements aren't already visible, so I can't access them. Is there a best practice on how to set view attibutes when creating a fragment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass the values in bundle and access them in onCreateView and call the related methods by passing those values.